# Python Couldnt find the key in Config file

Tags: python

Im using Python file on Apache as WSGI. The problem is i cant get the key from config file
and a this file run without problem when im using the python instead of Apache in eclipse
here is the file :

```
    import os
    import pymysql
    import json 
    from bottle import route, run ,request
    from configobj import ConfigObj
    config = ConfigObj('Config.ini')
    hostConfig = config['host']
    .....Program......
    application = bottle.default_app()
```

and config.ini file  :

```
    host = '127.0.0.1'
```

and this is the apache error.log  :

```
    hostConfig = config['host']
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configobj-4.7.2-py2.7.egg/configobj", line 567 , in __getitem__val = dict.__getitem__(self,key)
    KeyError : 'host'
```

Comment: Specify the absolute path for `Config.ini`.

Comment: Still same error after giving absolute path, plus if i give wrong path the error will change to "IOError : no such file or direcotry".
so i guess the program can find the 'Config.ini'

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct case?

Comment: yes , This project works without problem on Eclipse and Python compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah silly me ! I didnt fully read the deployment part of bottle in apache !

here is the link : http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html

after adding this line the problem solved :

```
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

best regard

Comment: I will , becuase atm when i click accpet this message apear "You can Accept Your Own answer Tomorrow" !